# Use values from database for bootstrap's typeahead

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap typeahead input set up and I have values in my database that I need to populate the typeahead with.

My database has a table called `pets` with a column called `name` (name of the pet). I need to make it so that the typeahead uses the values from the `name` column.

How is this done?

Comment: I know how to do this but only with jQuery UI's Autocomplete plugin. =/

Comment: For Bootstrap 3, use http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/. For 2.3, you can use a callback function that performs AJAX calls for the `source` attribute.